# Is it OK to link libraries from /usr/lib?

Tags: macos

I compiled a dynamic library for macOS (open source)
When I checked otool -L abc.dylib it shown that it links everal other libraries from /usr/lib/
Is it OK, or Apple may remove these libraries in future versions of macOS?

```
/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more suited for either Ask Different or Super User.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. It's important question.

Comment: Its importance has nothing to do with its topicality.  This is a system configuration issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: I meant, can my app rely on dynamic libraries located in /usr/lib ? This folder was distributed with macOS by Apple. Or these libs may disappears in future version of macOS?